# Finding locus point of three points

Tags: linear-algebra

GIVEN point $E(1,1)$, $F(5,3)$, $G(6,2)$. Find the locus of Point P that satisfies $EP^2+FP^2+GP^2=49$

Got $3x^2+3y^2-18x-14y-3=0$
where $x$ and $y$ is of P from substitution. Could you help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Have you tried completing the square? You should be able to get that into the standard form for the equation of a circle.

Comment: Got $(x-3)^2+(y- 7/3)^2=139/9$

Comment: How do i continue from this?

Comment: Its circle situated at $3,7/3$

Comment: Thank you i just didnt understand the term "locus" well.

Comment: I have included what locus means

Answer (score 0):

Ill give you a hint write equation as $(6^2)+(3^2)+(2^2)$ so now you know  the points E,G,F so by distance between two points generate two equations and get point $P(x,y)$ as you know the distances between FP,EP,GP . Other way is that you have equation of circle from that irs ckear irs a circle centred at $(3,7/3)$ so from there we can get locus and basically locus is generally a set of all points which satisfy given equations and parameters.

Comment: The distances $EP$, $FP$, and $GP$ are not known. All that is given is that $EP^2+FP^2+GP^2 = 49$. This is not enough to conclude that $EP = 6$, $FP = 3$, and $GP = 2$.

Comment: If it isnt what can we conclude